# How to handle nested synchronous promises

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

Here is the example JSON:

```
test = [
    [
        {
            "name": "Test1.1",
            "flow": [
                {
                    "send": "test1.1.1",
                    "receive": [...]
                },
                {
                    "send": "test1.1.2",
                    "receive": [...]
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Test1.2",
            "flow": [
                {
                    "send": "test1.2.1",
                    "receive": [...]
                },
                {
                    "send": "test1.2.2",
                    "receive": [...]
                },
            ]
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "name": "Test2.1",
            "flow": [
                {
                    "send": "test2.1.1",
                    "receive": [...]
                },
                {
                    "send": "test2.1.2",
                    "receive": [...]
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Test2.2",
            "flow": [
                {
                    "send": "test2.2.1",
                    "receive": [...]
                },
                {
                    "send": "test2.2.2",
                    "receive": [...]
                },
            ]
        }
    ]
 ]
```

I have successfully managed to run the test[0] with the following piece of code

```
describe('Conversations', function () {
    for (let test of arrayOfTests) {
        describe(test.name, () => {
            for (let x = 0; x < test.flow.length; x++) {
                let node = test.flow[x];
                it("Request: " + node.request, (done) => {
                    chai.request('http://localhost:5001').then(done())//WORK
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

However I start to run into issues when I attempt to pull in the entire test file and run each test one after another. I suspect it is likely due to the placement of the `done()` I've tired updating it in but I'm not entirely sure how to do it.

I've read there is a `it.each` however I'm not sure if that would help in my situation.

This is my attempt at testing the entire file which returns the error `Empty test suite.`

**Clean cut Question: How can I update the below code to work with the top most JSON.**

```
describe('Full Tests', () =>  {
    request(
        // Get testSuite
    }).then((allTests) => {
        for (let tests of allTests) {
            describe('Single test Array', () =>  {
                for (let test of tests) {
                    describe("Test: "+ test.name, () => {
                        for (let x = 0; x < test.flow.length; x++) {
                            let node = test.flow[x];
                            it("Request: " + node.request, (done) => {
                                chai.request('http://localhost:5001').then(done())//WORK
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: `done()` is called immediately. The function passed to `.then()` should be a function reference. You can use async/await to await the result of an asynchronous task within `for` loop

Comment: I suggest you take a look at mocha's "before, after, before each, after each hooks" https://mochajs.org/#hooks
It's not an answer, but it will help you writing your tests.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `async/await` to await the result of asynchronous tasks within a `for` loop

```js
(async(tests) => {
  const done = (value) => value;
  const results = [];
  try {
    for (let {test} of tests) {
      results.push(
          await Promise.all(
            test.map(n => 
              new Promise(resolve => {
                setTimeout(
                  resolve
                , n * 250
                , {result:n * 250 < 1000
                  , test:`${n} * 250 < 1000`
                  }
                )
              })
            )
          )
          .then(done))
    }
  } catch(err) {
    throw err
  }
  return results
})([{
  test: [1, 2, 3]
}, {
  test: [4, 5, 6]
}])

.then(data => console.log(data))
.catch(err => console.error(err))
```

Comment: HI thanks for this but I'm struggling to see how this would apply to my Mocha example / what is wrong with my current implementation?